# Using Q.js promise for unit-tests: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocha.js, q

I'm using Q.js library for simulating async behaviour by using `promise`

I have a stubed backend api

```
class ApiStub {
    constructor(){
        this.deferred = Q.defer();
    }

    post(url, data) {
        if (data) {
            this.deferred.resolve(data);
        } else {
            this.deferred.reject(new Error("Invalid data"));
        }
        return this.deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to test it:

```
 before(() => api = new ApiStub());

 it("Api test", (done) => {
        return api.post({})
            .then(value => {
                expect(value).to.exist;
                done();
            }, error => { 
               done(error);
            });
 });
```

but I got an `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

I've tried to set mocha timeout more then 15000ms but it didn't helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your error handler as part of the the same `then` with your test case. This means you won't [catch any errors thrown by the expect](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#user-content-the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern). Try this and see if you get a different error:

```
it("Api test", (done) => {
        return api.post({})
            .then(value => {
                expect(value).to.exist;
                done();
            }).catch(error => { 
                done(error);
            });
 });
```